# 'null' is not an object - samsung smart tv 3d

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv

I have the bellow code for switch samsung smart tv to 3d mode.but it shows an error on the console .

> TypeError : 'null' is not an object (Evaluating 'SefPlugin.Open')

```
Main.onLoad = function()
{

    this.enableKeys();
    widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();
    var SefPlugin = document.getElementById("plugin");
    SefPlugin.Open('Screen', '1.003', 'Screen');
    console.log(SefPlugin.Execute("Get3DEffectMode"));
    SefPlugin.Execute("Set3DEffectMode", MODE_3D_EFFECT_FROM_2D_TO_3D);


};
```

HTML CODE

```
         <html> 
         ----------------------- 
         <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/webapi/1.0/webapis.js"></script>

         </head>
     <body onload="Main.onLoad();" onunload="Main.onUnload();">
  <object id="plugin" classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-SEF" style="width:0px; height:0px;"></object>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Dcoumentation links http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/API00003/Screen_163

Comment: you may be getting `SefPlugin` as `undefined` in this line `var SefPlugin = document.getElementById("plugin");`. Make sure element with id plugin is there in DOM or you are accessing it with correct id name

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: @RohitAgrawal html added

Comment: @jcaron HTML is added in  the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use name attribute to access the object element.

```
...
 <object id="plugin" name="kekolama" classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-SEF" style="width:0px; height:0px;"></object>
...
```

and

```
var SefPlugin = document.kekolama;
```